# Using fill_between() plot in pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am having trouble plotting the area around the predictions of my model which I thought would be straightforward with fill_between plot.

For a reproducible example:

```
df1
  Ground_Truth  Predictions  Predictions_hi  Predictions_lo
410          15.0    14.810122       18.356809       11.263436
85           26.6    27.131472       28.320380       25.942565
280          45.4    45.404620       47.274549       43.534691
422          20.8    19.081849       20.711096       17.452601
199          34.9    29.703281       32.416996       26.989566
364          21.9    49.010702       52.162232       45.859172
5            28.7    27.330305       29.026654       25.633956
415           7.2     8.412145       10.244244        6.580046
209          20.0    17.257462       19.459939       15.054985
284          32.2    28.166823       30.390787       25.942859
```

The data in json format:

```
{"Ground_Truth":{"410":15.0,"85":26.6,"280":45.4,"422":20.8,"199":34.9,"364":21.9,"5":28.7,"415":7.2,"209":20.0,"284":32.2},"Predictions":{"410":14.8101220869,"85":27.1314724323,"280":45.4046198732,"422":19.0818488429,"199":29.7032811382,"364":49.0107021787,"5":27.3303047283,"415":8.4121453666,"209":17.2574622383,"284":28.1668228107},"Predictions_hi":{"410":18.3568086485,"85":28.3203798966,"280":47.2745488681,"422":20.7110962223,"199":32.4169963433,"364":52.1622320467,"5":29.0266538906,"415":10.2442444504,"209":19.4599393417,"284":30.3907868523},"Predictions_lo":{"410":11.2634355254,"85":25.9425649679,"280":43.5346908782,"422":17.4526014635,"199":26.989565933,"364":45.8591723107,"5":25.6339555659,"415":6.5800462828,"209":15.054985135,"284":25.9428587691}}
```

My code is the following:

```
results_df1.plot(x= 'Ground_Truth', y = 'Predictions', kind = 'scatter', color = 'r')
plt.plot(results_df1['Ground_Truth'],results_df1['Ground_Truth'], color = 'b')
plt.fill_between(results_df1['Ground_Truth'], results_df1['Predictions_lo'], results_df1['Predictions_hi'], alpha = 0.1)   
plt.show()
```

This code returns the following plot:

[image]

You see the jig-jag which I did not expect.

Comment: You would want to make sure the data you plot is sorted.

Comment: There's also a `where` parameter you can pass to `fill_between` to be more specific about where the fill is added.